# typeahead.js: How to make results auto-redirect to a URL that is generated based on the result?

Tags: typeahead.js

## What I have

A text input field that uses typeahead.js to display an array of values. These come from a php script that queries a MySql table.

HTML/JS:

```
<div class="FORM col-sm-3">
                <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" class="form-control" id="formsearch" name="formsearch" autocomplete="off" placeholder="FORM">
                </div>
<script>
$.get('searchers/forms.php', function(data){
    $("#formsearch").typeahead({ source:data });
},'json');
</script>
        </div>
```

searchers/forms.php:

```
<?php

include('../config/DBconnect.php');

$result = $con->query("SELECT id,name FROM forms LIMIT 0,10");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                     $user_arr[] = $row->id;
                              $user_arr2[] = $row->name;
                          }
     $result->close();
     echo json_encode($user_arr2);
?>
```

The above works, in the sense that it gives me a dropdown menu of options from the MySql table.

## What I'm trying to achieve

I'd like to have the results be URLs, that redirect upon selection.

The URLs will always have a pattern that relates to the value in the array. So if one listing is 'hello' the URL will be 'hello.php'

I have a few vague thoughts on how to maybe do this.

1. Have a URL column in the mysql table, although that could get repetitive for hundreds of entries
2. Get the PHP script to take the 'name' value, turn it into the relevant URL, then output that into the array. Typeahead would then have to distinguish between the two
3. Perform a similar function in Javascript

I'm new to the game and flying blind here, so I'm open to other suggestions as to how to go about this. I'm also unsure what it is I need to search for, so I apologise if someone has done this before me.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man the solution was staring me in the face.

```
$.get('searchers/forms.php', function(data){
        $("#formsearch").typeahead({
    source:data,
            updater: function (selectedName) {  
            window.location.href =[ selectedName ]+".php";  
                }  
});
 },'json');
```

Easy when you know how I guess.